# How can I select an area to screengrab in Lubuntu?

Tags: screenshot, lubuntu

I recently moved to Lubuntu and found that `alt` + `PrtSc` will screen grab the active window.
On Mint and Ubuntu, this key combination lets you manually select which part of the screen to capture,  similar to the Snipping Tool on Windows.

How can I enable this functionality on my machine? It saves a lot of time having to crop images in GIMP.

Comment: Almost all screenshot utilities include at least the ability to select an area.  Most include features like a delay, that allows you to capture open menus, and choosing whether to include the cursor.  The advanced ones include an editor that lets you do things like crop, annotate, etc.  If you normally have a browser open, there are lots of add-ons that add such features to the browser (and can be used for anywhere on the screen).  Lubuntu is barebones by design, and I forget what snapshot functionality is bundled.  (cont'd)

Comment: First try other modifier keys (Shift, Ctrl) with PrtSc to see if it's built-in.  If not, search the package manager for "screenshot" and see what utilities are offered in the repository.  You can add an icon to the system tray for easy access.